# Linear independence of a vectors satisfying certain relationships with respect to a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space, $T : V \to V$ a linear transformation, and $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be nonzero vectors in $V$ such that $T(v_1)=v_1, T(v_2)=v_1 + v_2, T(v_3)=v_2 + v_3.$
Prove that the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent.

I'm confused as to where to start. Does it involve using the properties of a linear transformation?

Answer (score 3):

A typical method for showing linear independence is to assume dependence and derive a contraction. Suppose the vectors are dependent, so that there are constants $\alpha_i$ not all zero so that
$$\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 = 0 .$$
Now, apply $T$ and use linearity.

Comment: So I apply T to each one, then I'm left with a1v1+a2(v2+v3)+a3(v2+v3)=0. I rearranged this to be v1(a1)+v2(a2+a3)+v3(a2+a3)=0. How am I supposed to show that these must equal 0?

Comment: You now have a system of two equations in $a_1, a_2, a_3$. Can you combine the equations to produce simpler one and deduce some information? (By the way, the second term in your first equation should be $\alpha_2 (v_1 + v_2)$.)